# Tate uniformization and reduction of elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, non-archimedean-fields

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $K$ (nonarchimedean) with $j$-invariant satisfying $|j(E)|>1$.
Tate uniformization theorem says that we have an isomorphism : $E \simeq \mathbf G_m/q^{\mathbf Z}$.

On the other hand, I can look at the reduction $\overline E$ of a minimal model of $E$ (see Silvermann, chap III of Arithmetic of elliptic curves).
My question is : why is $q^{1/3}$ reducing to a singular point of $\overline E$ ?

In more general terms : can I see $\overline E$ in terms of $q$ ?

Comment: The group of points of good reduction on a Weierstrass equation $y^2+xy=x^3+a_4 \, x +a_6$ consists of the points with $x$ and $y$ not in the maximal ideal as $a_4$ and $a_6$ have positive valuation. If $u$ has positive valuation, like $u=q^{1/3}$, then $x(u)$ has positive valuation and hence it gives a point of bad reduction. Therefore $E^0(K)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ injecting into $K^\times/q^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: The special fibre is an $c$-gon, where $c$ is the valuation of $q$, i.e. the Tamagawa number. The group of components identifies with $\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}$ induced by the valuation $K^\times \to \mathbb{Z}$. If you need explicit equations of the special fibre of the Néron model you will need to blow up the Weierstrass equation $c/2$ times.The connected component are the points on the nodal cubic $y^2+xy=x^3$. The reduction map from $E^0(K)$ correspond to the reduction of $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ modulo the $1+$ the maximal ideal. -- All of this can be found in Silverman's Advanced AEC.